# Implementing push_back() function of vector cause unintended output?

Tags: c++

I'm trying [a very noob way to implement vector](https://github.com/p1v0t/vector/tree/develop) as an exercise. I write bunch of functions and seems to work fine but when I tried to push a series of value it cause different output than I expect.

My type definitions are:

```
template <typename T, class Allocator = allocator<T>> class vector {
public:
  // type definitions
  using allocator_type = Allocator;
  using value_type = T;

  using reference = value_type &;
  using const_reference = const value_type &;

  using pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer;
  using const_pointer =
      typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_pointer;

  using iterator = value_type *;
  using const_iterator = const value_type *;

  using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
  using const_reverse_iterator = const std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

  using size_type = std::size_t;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

  // member variables
  allocator_type m_allocator;
  T *m_data = nullptr;

  size_type m_capacity = 10;
  size_type m_size = 0;
  ...
```

and the `push_back()` function is:

```
template <typename T, class Allocator>
constexpr void vector<T, Allocator>::push_back(const T &val_) {
  m_data[m_size++] = val_;

  if (m_size > capacity()) {
    m_capacity = m_size * 2;
    m_data = m_allocator.allocate(m_capacity);
  }
}
```

When I try:

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  p1v0t::vector<int> iv;

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
    iv.push_back(i);
  }

  for (auto item : iv) {
    std::cout << item << ' ';
  }
}
```

it gives an output like: 
`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 11 12 13 14`

What are the possible reasons for it? Any shout out for I make stupid is welcome...

Comment: Look up how to use gdb and litter your code with std::cout to see what's going on internally.

Answer (score 4):

You test capacity after adding the element:

```
m_data[m_size++] = val_;

if (m_size > capacity()) {
```

So if m_size == capacity, then you insert past the end, and only then resize the data area.

Since initial capacity is 10, you first have the issue in your example when inserting 11th element. Then `m_size` == 10 and `capacity` == 10 upon entry.

→ You insert `val_` at `m_data[10]`.

Also you might want to check how you use allocator. With a usual allocator you would need to copy items over to newly allocated area after increasing the capacity (and freeing old area). We cannot know for sure from your post, Allocator might be a custom one of yours with non-standard behavior.

Comment: Given the zeroes below index 10, I'm pretty sure it's not some special allocator with non-standard behavior. The data prior to resize was just dropped on the floor, and fresh zeroes were left in its place.

Comment: It is, indeed, very likely. But I saw your answer pop when I was about to elaborate and it perfectly covers that part, so I figured I'd just upvote it. Thus he has two answers, each detailing one of his bugs.

Answer (score 3):

```
m_data = m_allocator.allocate(m_capacity);
```

That allocates new memory, replacing the old pointer, but the old pointer is discarded (leaked), along with its data. You need to have both new and old pointers in existence at once, copy from old to new, the delete the old and replace it with the new.

As the other answer notes, your capacity increase is occurring at the wrong time; simply moving the check ahead of the assignment of the new element and tweaking it to test `>=` rather than `>` would fix that though.